# creating socks proxy

Tags: boot, ssh

I'm trying to create a socks proxy on my Raspberry Pi. For that I have this command: `ssh -f -N -C -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost`.

Now I want to run that on startup. And here is the problem. When I put the line into the `/etc/rc.local` file, the proxy starts, but I can't connect to it. I guess it isn't working, because I have to enter the user password, when I run the code by myself. I want to login into it with php and without a key. I prefer user + password or just without user.

Is there a simple way to run that line of code on startup with all user rights that it needs?

Comment: maybe [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) will help - i.e. *ssh public key authentication*

Comment: I read a lot of times about that. But I want to login into it with php and without a key. I prefer user + password or just without user. Don’t worry, I’m working with iptables

Comment: that's OK, I'm not worried at all

Comment: You can configure ssh to use a public key *or* a password.  Using the key will make it easier to automate, then you can use the password when you log in manually. I'm not sure if it will work for a user with no password or not, but you can try.